# Need to add image in tab bar items where “More” button will be there

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I am now working in a universal application. Here the deployment target i iOS 6.0 and I am working on Xcode 6.0.1 with Objective-C. I am facing problem to put image on tab bar items. I will have 6 or 7 tab bar items in the tab bar controller, so that by default a “More” button will appear.

I need to set image on each tab bar item.

I need help.

Answer (score 0):

If the tab bar controller is your root view controller, you could probably do this in 'didFinishLaunching..' in appdeleagte.

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController=(UITabBarController*) (self.window.rootViewController);
UITabBar *tabBar=tabBarController.tabBar;
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1=[[tabBar items] objectAtIndex:0];//first tab bar
UIImage* selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
[tabBarItem1 setImage:selectedImage];
```

Answer (score 0):

Add custom image to Tabbar

```
UITabBarItem *first = [[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"First" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"first.png"] selectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"second.png"]];
[self.tabBarController setTabBarItem:first];
```